# Staying authenticated after the page is refreshed using Passportjs

Tags: javascript, session, express, mongoose, passport.js

I am building a SPA using **express**, **mongoose** and **passportjs**.

I have created a simple schema for my user:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

var User = new Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    first_name: String
}, { collection: 'users' });

User.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

mongoose.model('User', User);
```

Configured passport using the `User` object which mongoose gave me:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());         
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

And configured my app to authenticate the user when navigating to this route:

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return res.json({ state: 'success', user: { first_name: req.user.first_name } });    
    }
    return res.json({ state: 'failure', message: 'cannot authenticate' });
});
```

Now I am able to successfully authenticate a user. And the browser saves a session id cookie.

My problem is that every time the user refreshes the page passport won't deserialize the user using the session id, what makes the user unauthenticated.

While accessing the `req.user` object in the site's root I get `undefined` what make me realize passport doesn't deserialize the user properly:

```
app.use('/', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.user); // prints undefined.        

    next();
});
```

**What is the proper way for restoring a user after refreshing the page?**

Comment: Mongoose must be deserializing the user, if you're calling `passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to store the sessions in the **DB**. I used [connect-mongo](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo).

app.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var expressSession = require('express-session');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(expressSession);

mongoose.connect(db_url, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});

app.use(expressSession({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET || 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
}));
```

after this, `req.isAuthenticated()` returns `true` on every request even after refreshing the page. (Thanks to `app.use(passport.session())` which comes before any route handler)

```
app.use('/', function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        // returns true if a user already logged in.
    }
    next();
});
```

Comment: var session = require('express-session');  
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo/es5')(express);  
app.use(express.session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET || 'this is the secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
}));  
Its still login out whenever I refresh??

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your post i can guess where problem is happening. In question you have pasted your back end expressjs code, but the problem is happening in the front end.

Think of a situation when you are working on normal javascript files, you make some edit in the variable values using Chrome dev tools of firebug n all. Let's say you  refresh the page, do you still see the same edited value in the view? No right. Same is the case with your view, you are temporary holding user data. Although your backend is holding the values in **req.user** but your front end loses it when you refresh.

So you have to do either of below two :

- Store your value in cookie on successful login and erase it when
  logged out. So that cookie is never going to loose data even if you
  refresh the page. Access the user data from that cookie whenever you need it
- Call the backend API which returns value of req.user on your every
  page refresh

I am not sure what frontend framework you are using for SPA, if you are using **AngularJS** then you can make use of [cookieStore](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore) service it does the job beautifully.

Comment: The problem is that I can see the `sessionid` cookie in my browser by using Chrome dev tools even after refreshing the page. And yes, I am using **AngularJS**

Comment: I tried to explain you the possible case. The value in front end gets flushed after refresh and you need to call `req.user` to get it back.

Comment: Ok so this is probably not the case because I can see that the value is still alive after refreshing the page, and when I try to access `req.user` I get `undefined`